# Installed script with pip: Run like a command

Tags: command-line, python, pip

I installed this python script [scdl](https://github.com/flyingrub/scdl) to download audio from soundcloud. The script is installed to ~/.local/bin
How can I run this script in a terminal like a programm? So I don't enter the whole path to this script. I would like to run it like this:

```
scdl - l <link>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add the path `~/.local/bin` to the `PATH` environment.

Open the file `.bashrc` in a terminal

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

and add

```
:$HOME/.local/bin
```

at the end of the `PATH` definition

e.g.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin
```

and add the line:

```
alias my_app="scdl - l <link>"
```

to start your command `scdl - l <link>` with the alias `my_app`.

Replace `my_app` with a name of your choice.

Start the command to read the configuration

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

That's all.

Comment: Closing the terminal window and reopening another one also works to reload the `.bashrc` file. Not that yours is wrong, just another option. Good answer btw.

Comment: there was no path enviroment so i added this line at the end of the file.
now it works fine!
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Or simpler way...
Just create a symlink to it in `/usr/local/bin/`

eg.

`sudo ln -s /home/user/.local/bin/scdl /usr/local/bin/scdl`

Then its automatically added to the default PATH